# How long will it take Pixel and Tonic to release Craft 3?

Tags: craft3

I am just wondering, when will Pixel and Tonic release Craft 3 stable version?

Comment: When it's ready.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked them on twitter regarding this yesterday and got the [following answer](https://twitter.com/CraftCMS/status/783272809661292544):

> Hope to have Craft 3 in beta by the end of year.

Comment: Do we have any update for the final release date?

Answer (score 4):

It will be released before the end of Q1 2017 as stated in the yearly round up in December.

Comment: Highly keen for the beta version, but only 23 days to go!